# Combining context menu with custom interface in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I need to combine a custom ribbon with a context menu in an Excel file. I have been using custom ribbons and context menus with RibbonX separately for several years.

The code below doesn't seem to load either of them.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="MyCustomTab" label="Client Tool"  insertAfterMso="TabTEAM">
                
                <group id="customGroup1" label="Add">
                    <button id="customButton1" label="New Product" size="large" onAction="NewProduct" />
                    <separator id="MySeparator1" /> 
                 <button id="customButton2" label="New Column" size="large" onAction="NewColumn" /> 
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
     
    <contextMenus>
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">

            <menu id="MySubMenu" label="Client Menu" insertBeforeMso="Cut" image="clientlogo" >
                <button id="Menu1Button1" label="Set as Relevant" 
                    imageMso="AppointmentColor0" onAction="UpperMacro"/>
                <button id="Menu1Button2" label="Set as Irrelevant" 
                    imageMso="AppointmentColor4" onAction="LowerMacro"/>
            </menu>
            <menuSeparator id="MySeparator" insertBeforeMso="Cut" />
        </contextMenu>
    </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Try changing the `<ribbon>` to '<ribbon startFromScratch="false">`  If it works, the same flag may work for the context menus as well (unsure of this)

Comment: Thanks,@glenn-g! I tried insert this for the ribbon part only. When I opened the file in Excel the context menu worked. When opening the file in the Office RibbonX Editor afterwards the ribbon part had disappeared.